# React обнаружил изменение порядка хуков, вызванных

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Билжу программу и прилетает такая вот ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нарушается правило хуков: хуки вызываются только из React-функций или из других хуков.
getString - не React-функция и не хук.

Нужно перенести `const { stdout } = useStdout()` в Bar.
Добавить в `getString` ещё один параметр - `stdout`.